# Cant cast multiple recyclerview items with their ID

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to cast my `RecyclerView` layout id in order to not repeat the code

I have 3 `RecyclerView`'s in my layout, what I want to do is to have just one method that takes the RecyclerView ids and setups them without their adapter yet.

What I have done is this:

```java
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setupRecyclerViewLayoutManager(R.id.first_rv)
    setupRecyclerViewLayoutManager(R.id.second_rv)
    setupRecyclerViewLayoutManager(R.id.third_rv)

}

private fun setupRecyclerViewLayoutManager(recyclerViewId:Int){
    val recyclerView = recyclerViewId as RecyclerView
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
}
```

But this code fails with the cast

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
>           at com.ui.home.HomeFragment.setupRecyclerViewLayoutManager(HomeFragment.kt:36)
>           at com.ui.home.HomeFragment.onViewCreated(HomeFragment.kt:29)

Why I cant cast the integer ids of those `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing Int id not RecyclerView itself.

You can do like this:

```
private fun setupRecyclerViewLayoutManager(view: View, recyclerViewId:Int){
    val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(recyclerViewId)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
}
```

Usage:

```
setupRecyclerViewLayoutManager(view,R.id.first_rv)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    setupRecyclerViewLayoutManager(view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.first_rv))
}

private fun setupRecyclerViewLayoutManager(recyclerView: RecyclerView){
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
}
```

You should do it this way